# rrdtool get average value over the last week

Tags: rrdtool

I'm trying to get the average value over last week week from a rra file.

/var/www/html/cacti/rra/traffic.rrd

What I am doing right now is using the following command to get all the data over the last week then compute the average using other programming languages.

```
rrdtool fetch /var/www/html/cacti/rra/traffic.rrd AVERAGE -s -7d
```

I wonder if there are any 'native way' to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 2):

there is

```
rrdtool graph dummy --start=end-7d --end=now \
  DEF:x=/var/www/html/cacti/rra/traffic.rrd:in:AVERAGE \
  VDEF:xa=x,AVERAGE PRINT:xa:%lf
```

this will print out the average value of the DS 'in' over the last 7 days.